# Ampère's circuital law in case of uniform current density in infinite space

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations

Let's have an ideal conductor with current density $\mathbf{J}$. The ideal conductor takes up the entire space, effectively resulting in the entire space $\mathbb{R}^3$ being permeated with $\mathbf J$.

In case of uniform current density $\mathbf{J}$ taking up the entire space, $\mathbf{E}$ being $0$ everywhere, what's $\mathbf{B}$ everywhere in space? I thought it would be $0$ (because the contributions from all elementary currents should cancel each other out), but that seems to contradict Ampère's circuital law

$\nabla\times \mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}+\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$, since

$0\neq\mu_0\mathbf{J}$.

Is, in that case, $\mathbf{B}=0$ everywhere, is the entire situation incompatible with Maxwell's equations, or some third possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my poor english !

I think we can go into steady state and forget about the electric field.

The problem is well known for infinite volume charges distributions. In particular for a volume distribution of uniform charge for which "by symmetry" the electric field should be zero, non compatible with the Maxwell Gauss equation.

In the case of the uniform current density, I think that the Biot and Savart integral is not really convergent. It depends on how to stretch the limits to infinity. We only find $0$ if we stretch the limits to infinity symmetrically. For example, if the current distribution is cylindrically symmetrical, of radius $R$, the field at the distance   from the axis is ${{B}_{\theta }}=\frac{1}{2}{{\mu }_{0}}jr$. If we stretch $R$ to infinity, this field does not tend to $0$.

The symmetry arguments are not usable either because the solution of the Maxwell equations is not unique.

In the end, one should expect difficulties with non-physical charges or currents distributions. We can consider ourselves lucky to have to have so few problems with infinite surface and linear distributions!

I can try to clarify a bit (it's too long for a simple comment) :

You will notice that when we study Gauss' theorem we consider the infinite straight wire, the infinite plane but never the "infinite cube".

I think that the passage to the limit of an infinite volume distribution is not consistent with the equations of electromagnetism. In particular, there is no longer a single solution.

I also think that the arguments that give a zero integral are not convincing because the limit of the integral depends totally on how one makes the boundaries to infinity. A bit like someone who would prove that $\sum\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{{{(-1)}^{k}}}=0$ that because at each 1 we can associate a -1 !

Comment: Thanks. So Maxwell's equations aren't compatible with $\varrho=const.\neq0$ everywhere in space, not only Ampère's law, but e.g. Gauss' law too, because it predicts that $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\varrho}{\varepsilon_0}$, which would result in $0 = \frac{\varrho}{\varepsilon_0}\neq0$. The general answer, therefore, is that the situation is impossible to begin with because Maxwell's equations are incompatible with $\varrho$ being a nonzero constant everywhere in space. Is that right?

Comment: Even though nobody confirmed that my interpretation of your answer was correct, I'm sufficiently confident that I can accept your answer and rely on my interpretation of it. Thanks!

Comment: I am also surprised that so few people have answered your question. I tried to complete the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I already upvoted your answer before, but it didn't show because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats! What you've discovered, more or less, is that the case of an infinite uniform *current* density pervading all space in *magnetostatics* is the complementary notion to the case of an infinite uniform *charge* density pervading all space in *electrostatics*. And it is well-known that in this case, such conditions do not uniquely specify the electric field; likewise, here, they do not uniquely specify the magnetic field. That is, this is a place where the laws of EM theory are *non-predictive*. The reason this is not a problem is quite simply that the Universe is not either a uniform charge *or* current distribution, and thus this pathology is not encountered.

Many physical theories have these kinds of pathologies - another example is that Newtonian mechanics admits a structure called "Norton's dome" in which that many possible future evolutions are consistent with the equations of motion from the same initial conditions, however this structure is not one we can physically realize because it requires a perfectly ideal mathematically pointed surface and point particle resting thereupon, neither of which are possible in the "real" Universe thanks to atoms and to quantum mechanics, the former of which prevents the pointed surfaces, and the latter of which prevents a state of simultaneous complete rest and fully-determined location of a point particle from ever happening. Moreover, it may be that "point" particles like electrons aren't even truly points at all, as in string theory, though this is purely hypothetical as of now. No evidence for string theory has ever been found. Yet another example is the idea of a "naked singularity" in general relativity, which was actually discussed in a recent thread here concerning black holes.

Generically, the "solution" to these is to note that the conditions they require turn out to be "absurd" in some way, as in the infinite uniform density, or the notion of the need for a surface with mathematically ideal properties. The naked singularity one is a bit more troublesome because it is actually still a wide open problem as to whether or not that a realistic physical process might result in one (this is the so-called "cosmic censorship problem"), or what general relativity would say is one.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that the electric field inside an ideal conductor with uniform $J$ is zero, that doesn't imply the magnetic field inside it of it will be zero.

In fact, you can easily calculate the magnetic field inside an ideal conductor with uniform current density $\vec{J}$ using Ampere's law integral version:

$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=\mu_0 I$$

In general just because $E$ or $B$ is zero in a region of space doesn't necessarily mean the other should also be zero. So there's no contradiction here.

Comment: Isn't the Ampere Law $\int Bd l =\mu I$?

Comment: Thanks, I know $\mathbf{E}=0$ doesn't imply $\mathbf{B}=0$, my question was about the ideal conductor being spatially infinite, not just *any* ideal conductor.

Comment: @KarthikV Yes, it is. (As long as there are no other currents aside from $I$, or as long as we include the other currents in $I$.)

Comment: Right. So does $dS$ mean the circumference element in your formula?

Comment: @KarthikV I'm the author of the question, I didn't write the answer. 

Comment: Sorry I messed up, it is indeed $\vec{dI}$, which represents the curve that encompasses the element of surface you're analyzing. By the way, this also applies for an infinite spatial conductor, the validity of the law isn't limited by such case.

Comment: Thanks, but I already realized, thanks to @VincentFraticelli, that it's not possible, because it would lead to a contradiction as I wrote in my question. (You can try to calculate it for yourself, let me know what result did you get, and I'll show how it leads to a contradiction.)

Comment: By the way, you didn't [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) anyone in your comment, so neither I nor @KarthikV were messaged about it. 

Comment: If you edit your answer to be more like Vincent Fraticelli's, I'll reverse my downvote (but it won't show because I don't have enough reputation). (Right now, the answer doesn't apply for infinite conductors (try to calculate $\mathbf B$ and tell me what it should be).)

Comment: Also, I just realized what you mean - you're talking about a finite conductor of a specific shape, which is then made infinite by taking the limit to infinity. *Then* you could use Ampère's law. But what I mean is an infinite space filled with uniform $\mathbf J$ without any specific procedure that you could take a limit of. So in that case, that law can't be used, because the answer depends on how we take the limit. (So we obtain infinitely many solutions, each for one way of taking the limit, which is just another way of saying that we can't find the answer.)

Comment: (In addition to that, there is the symmetry argument according to which $\mathbf B$ should be $0$, which further illustrates that the solution can't be found.)